# How to get active page in bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Carousel and I want to get active page index when slide event occurs. I searched the internet and find 2 events: `slide.bs.carousel` and `slid.bs.carousel` but I couldn't get active page index. Is there any way?

Comment: maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044805/how-to-trigger-bootstrap-carousels-carousel-indicators/37045506#37045506) will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the jQuery [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`.index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) methods to get a 0 based index of which slide is currently marked as active.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var carouselEl = $('.carousel');
    var carouselItems = carouselEl.find('.item');
    carouselEl.carousel({
      interval: 2000
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function (event) {
        console.log(carouselItems.siblings('.active').index());
    })
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4c4my1a3/)**